# How do i loop through an array of dates in angular template

Tags: angular

I have a function that gets company's year it started so if the company started in the 2019, the function stores the years like [2019,2020,2021] respectively. But the for loop in my function is what i want to be written in html and not the ts.

This function is returning an array of years, so if i use this in the html i get all the years considered as one clickable link, but i want to have each year clickable so i want to be able to loop through the years in the html.

```
getLastYear() {
    const startYear = this.org.createdAt.getFullYear();
    const now = new Date();
    const currentYear = now.getFullYear();

    let arrayOfYears = [];
    for (let year = startYear; year <= currentYear - 1; year++) {
      arrayOfYears.push(year);
    }
    return arrayOfYears;
  }

 <a *ngIf="canShowLastYear()" [routerLink]="['.']" routerLinkActive="active" [queryParams]="{hmRange: getLastYear()}" [queryParamsHandling]="'merge'" >{{ getLastYear() }}</a>
```

Comment: have you try *ngFor ??

Comment: the problem here is, the loop is in this function how do i twerk it to use it the html.

Comment: I dont understand what you just wrote. However, I have an idea that you want to modify your array using template - if so, dont go that way as it is an anti pattern. Having it in the component is clear and testable.

Comment: It is really not clear what you want. Why do you want to remove the ts code? Besides the name of the function totally doesn't fit it's semanctics.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, the problem here is this function used to do just one thing and now am modifying it to do what i am looking for that is why the name is still the same.

Comment: Hello, @SheriffSulemana. If I understood correct, you want to move logic of `getLastYear()` function into your `.html` template. Honestly, this is bad idea because in Angular you have to avoid any logic in your templates. Even call TS methods, like `<div>{{myFunc()}}</div>`, from the template is a bad practice. Please, find another solution but not put your functions in the `HTML`.

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved it by twerking the function and ng-container is used in other to contain the two structural directives. it works fine.

```js
getLastYear() {
    const startYear = this.org.createdAt.getFullYear();
    const now = new Date();
    const currentYear = now.getFullYear();
    const years = [...Array(currentYear - startYear).keys()].map(
      (e) => e + startYear
    );

    return years;
  }
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="canShowLastYear()">
              <a  *ngFor="let year of getLastYear()" [routerLink]="['.']" routerLinkActive="active" [queryParams]="{hmRange: year}" [queryParamsHandling]="'merge'" >
                <span>{{ year }}</span>
              </a> |
            </ng-container>
```